# Ambiguous Column Error In SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT IB,* 
FROM SaleOrder 
WHERE IB IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY IB
```

Error :

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Ambiguous column name 'IB'.

Can somebody please explain why am I getting error while executing above SQL statement in SQL Server 2012 whereas same runs fine in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Why it ever worked is because the product wasn't behaving as per the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.100).aspx): "If *order_by_expression* is not qualified, the value must be unique among all columns listed in the SELECT statement."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your SQL Server 2008 database is in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode, because [normally it should return the same error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33250) as your 2012 instance.

Try fully qualifying the table name in your query and running it in SQL Server 2008 in the context of a database with the default compatibility level (e.g. in the context of `tempdb`), and you will likely see the error.

The difference in behaviour is by design and is documented in [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) as follows (emphasis added):

> **Compatibility-level setting of 80**
>
> …
>
> When binding the column references in the ORDER BY list to the columns defined in the SELECT list, ***column ambiguities are ignored*** and column prefixes are sometimes ignored. This can cause the result set to return in an unexpected order.

Answer (score 0):

Your table already contains column **IBID** so in `ORDER BY` clause sql server is not able to decide which column to access and sort by , **IBID** from table obtained in * or IBIS column specified at beginning in `SELECT` list

```
Select IBID,s.* from SaleHeader s WHERE IBID IS NOT NULL Order BY s.IBID
```

specify an alias to table as shown above

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from SaleHeader WHERE IBID IS NOT NULL Order BY IBID
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the column `IBID` occurs twice in your results now.

You should either add an alias or remove the column.

So either this:

```
Select * from SaleHeader WHERE IBID IS NOT NULL Order BY IBID
```

Or:

```
Select s.IBID colX,* from SaleHeader s WHERE s.IBID IS NOT NULL Order BY s.IBID
```

About the 'why':

Is the query exact the same? Maybe the interpreter is different on both platforms. Is there a difference in your use of this query? (for example, do you run this separately or as a view definition. that differs a lot in how it is analyzed)

Comment: Thats but obvious, but why the same works in SQL Server 2008 and not in SQL Server 2012??? Why???

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are selecting `IBID` column twice.

Try:

```
Select * from SaleHeader WHERE IBID IS NOT NULL Order BY IBID
```

Answer (score 0):

your table have already that column. if you use 2 times column in one query than sql server need to specify which table column want to access. use **tablename.column** name in order by.

```
SELECT IBID,* 
FROM SaleHeader 
WHERE IBID IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY SaleHeader.IBID
```